# Firebase custom event for ios "notification_open" not showing on dashboard

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-notifications

I know that *notification_open* is used by Firebase on Android but not on ios.
Can I use **notification_open** as a custom event name on iOS app?

Comment: I think you shouldn't use it in anycase

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use preserved event names in [Automatically collected events](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317485), after I change to something like `ios_notification_open`, it shows up in Firebase Analytics dashboard